# Source-to-target mapping document

Tags: mapping, data-modeling, datamodel, data-management, master-data-management

When we say source-to-target mapping document, does it typically include all the mappings between the different layers?

For example, given the following lineage:

source systems -> staging tables -> EDW -> data marts

Would there be 3 separate mapping documents?
(i.e., 1. source systems to staging tables 2. staging tables to EDW and 3. EDW to data marts)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you manage your documentation but general practice is 2 different source 2 target document:

1. Source System --> EDW
2. EDW --> Data Mart